# Optimizing HTTP request and multiple Split on CSV file

Tags: c#, arrays, list, http

I'm trying to read a CSV file from a website, then split the initial string by `\n`, then split again by `,`.
When I try to print out the content of one of the arrays, it was very slow, it takes almost one second between each `Console.WriteLine()` that prints each element.

I'm not entirely sure why it takes such great deal of time to print.

Any pointers will help

```
public List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
    public List<string[]> Content
    {
        get
        {
            using (var url = new WebClient())
            {
                _content = url.DownloadString("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DDhAd98p5RwXqvV53P2YvaujIQEg28HjeXasrCge9Qo/pub?output=csv");
            }
            var urlArr = _content.Split('\n');

            foreach (var i in urlArr)
            {
                var contentArr = i.Split(',');
                List.Add(contentArr);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
```

Main

```
 var data = new ReadCSV(); 

 for(var i = 0; i < data.Content[2].Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(data.Content[2][i]);
```

Comment: Hint: put a debugger breakpoint somewhere in the `get` body.

Answer (score 1):

You should cache the results in a variable, either in the `Content` property or before the loop because currently your code downloads and split the string every time in the loop which is why it is taking 1 second

So, your code should look like this:

```
var data = new ReadCSV(); 
var content = data.Content[2];

 for(var i = 0; i < content.Length; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(content[2][i]);
```